# Javascript parse JSON data from from input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am stuck on the last step of my data flow. Right now I am working on building an app that takes input from a HTML form input field and through Ajax returns data associated with what the user inputs. I'll try and explain better below.

Step 1:

User fills out form that asks for website url:

```
<form action="return.php" class="url-performance" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
   <input type="text" name="target_url" value="" placeholder="yourwebsite.com" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
<div class="the-return"></div>
```

Step 2:

After that this data is submitted to return.php which is actually an ajax function in my main js file:

```
  $(".url-performance").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "../wp-content/themes/company/response.php", 
      data: data,
      success: function(
        $(".the-return").html(
          "url: http://api.url" + data["target_url"]
        );
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Step 3:

Data is finally passed through response.php

```
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function(); break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){
  $return = $_POST;

  $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
  echo json_encode($return);
}
```

The issue I am running into is that I need to get the JSON data from http://api.url" + data["target_url"]. It will look like:

```
{
USS001: {
node_id: "AWSUS1",
domain: "dyn.com",
results: [
{
nameserver: "ns1.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.70.1",
ip: "199.180.184.220",
query_time: 2
},
{
nameserver: "ns2.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.250.1",
ip: "199.180.184.220",
query_time: 5
},
{
nameserver: "ns3.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.71.1",
ip: "199.180.184.220",
query_time: 2
},
{
nameserver: "ns4.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.251.1",
ip: "199.180.184.220",
query_time: 11
}
],
query_time: 2,
nameserver_used: "ns1.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_used_ip: "208.78.70.1",
test_time: 0.13942
},
EUS001: {
node_id: "EUS001",
domain: "dyn.com",
results: [
{
nameserver: "ns3.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.71.1",
ip: "134.0.76.51",
query_time: 1
},
{
nameserver: "ns2.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.250.1",
ip: "134.0.76.51",
query_time: 8
},
{
nameserver: "ns1.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.70.1",
ip: "134.0.76.51",
query_time: 1
},
{
nameserver: "ns4.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.251.1",
ip: "134.0.76.51",
query_time: 7
}
],
query_time: 1,
nameserver_used: "ns3.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_used_ip: "208.78.71.1",
test_time: 0.33029
},
HKS001: {
node_id: "HKS001",
domain: "dyn.com",
results: [
{
nameserver: "ns3.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.71.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 6
},
{
nameserver: "ns4.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.251.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 122
},
{
nameserver: "ns2.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.250.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 11
},
{
nameserver: "ns1.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.70.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 6
}
],
query_time: 6,
nameserver_used: "ns3.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_used_ip: "208.78.71.1",
test_time: 0.68504
},
AUS001: {
node_id: "AUS001",
domain: "dyn.com",
results: [
{
nameserver: "ns2.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.250.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 1
},
{
nameserver: "ns1.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.70.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 2
},
{
nameserver: "ns3.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "208.78.71.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 1
},
{
nameserver: "ns4.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_ip: "204.13.251.1",
ip: "103.11.201.138",
query_time: 2
}
],
query_time: 1,
nameserver_used: "ns2.p01.dynect.net",
nameserver_used_ip: "204.13.250.1",
test_time: 1.30983
}
}
```

What I am stuck on is finding the javascript equivalent to file_get_contents (php).

Comment: So, you want to parse JSON? It should by itself. Try adding the content-type header in your php before `json_encode`

Comment: why is `PHP` involved in this at all this can all be done client side.

Comment: @cmorrissey I am new to all of this. What would be an example of doing it all client side?

Comment: You could just post to the API by changing `url: "../wp-content/themes/company/response.php",` to `url: 'http://api.url' + $('input[name="target_url"]').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Check the output in ajax success using

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: He is using `dataType: "json"`, it will parse by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You double-encode your data...

```
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
```